# Running a SQL query through DB2 Command Line Processor and viewing the output result in notepad++

Tags: sql, db2, notepad++

I am able to execute a select query through DB2 Command Line Processor and view the output result in notepad++.

C:\db2cmd>db2 "select * from employee fetch first 5 rows only" > output.txt

When I open output.txt in Notepad++ , then output display is as shown below, After each and every line, carriage return(CR) and Line Feed(LF) is occuring.

---

```
           92881                    0     13      1223
                                      
           92886                    0     17      1224
                                      
           92890                    0     20      1225
                                      
           92892                    0     21      1226
                                      
           92896                    0     24      1227
```

5 records.

Why the CR LF occurs while opening the output query result .txt in notepad++? How to remove the CR LF between each records. I am expecting the output as shown below,

[image]

Comment: In Notepad++ select menu => View => Show symbol => Show end of line. Then [edit] your question to explain what end-of-line symbols are shown.

Comment: Use `db2 -r output.txt "select * from employee fetch first 5 rows only"` instead.